# Is this a correct way of Transforming lambda construct into a ordinary function?

Tags: python, lambda

lambda is new for me and I'm trying to understand the mechanism of lambda by transforming it into a ordinary function . I saw this code :

```
def add(n):
    return lambda x: n+x

print add(5)(3)
#output is 8
```

So I tried to transform this code into a ordinary function located inside a function :

```
def add(n):
    def other(x):
        return n+x
    return other(3)

print add(5)
#output is 8
```

Their outputs were the same but since I'm new in learning lambdas , is this a correct way to transform them? Or is there a better way than the way I did ?

Comment: These two pieces of code are different because in one of them, the 3 is outside of the add function, and in the other, the 3 is inside the add function. With the first code block, you can add 4 and 4 without changing `add`'s definition. With the second code block, you can only change one of the numbers, at best adding 4 and 3.

Comment: That's right ... Thanks :-))))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is valid code, but it defeats the purpose of using the lambda.

Often, you'll return a lambda to delay part of the execution until later. You can see that in the first example. `add` returns a function that does some math. The caller can then call the returned function now, or later if they want to delay the execution until they have the second part of the data.

Really, your second example should just be:

```
def add(n):
    return n + 3
```

Since it calls the lambda immediately anyways.

Comment: Thanks :-)))))))))))